# Use css selector to select all div elements with some class, but without style attribute

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm writing a crawler with [wombat](https://github.com/felipecsl/wombat/). And somehow i'm using CSS selectors, not XPATH. And i have very difficult selection here - that i can't achieve using css.

I have div elements that i want to grab from a page:

```
<div class="do_cat_ads_box"> ... </div>
<div class="do_cat_ads_box2"> ... </div>
<div class="do_cat_ads_box" style=".."> ...</div>
<div class="do_cat_ads_box2" style=".."> ... </div>
```

But elements with 'style' attribute - are garbage (ads) that i don't need.

So my question is, can I grab all div elements with classes 'do_cat_ads_box' and 'do_cat_ads_box2', but avoid div elements that have 'style' attribute?

I ended up with something like this and it is not working:

```
application 'css=div.do_cat_ads_box2, div.do_cat_ads_box,  div.do_cat_ads_box:not(@style)', :iterator do
  href 'css=div.do_cat_ads_image  a @href'
  name 'css=div.do_cat_ads_detail a'
end
```

if it's not double with css selectors, then there is always xpath way. But i'm very interested in css-selectors approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Attribute selectors in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) use `[attr]` notation. The `@attr` notation pertains to attribute locators (as well as XPath).

Assuming Wombat supports the CSS syntax for attribute selectors, try changing `:not(@style)` to `:not([style])` and rewriting your class selectors to the following:

```
application 'css=div.do_cat_ads_box:not([style]), div.do_cat_ads_box2:not([style])', :iterator do
  href 'css=div.do_cat_ads_image  a @href'
  name 'css=div.do_cat_ads_detail a'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Grabbing all elements that have a class defined is pretty simple:

`div[class]`

Modern CSS3-compliant browsers ([caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)) also have a :not() selector, allowing you to access all divs with classes but no styles:

`div[class]:not([style])`

If your browser or HTML parser supports only CSS2, you'll have to either use jQuery (which supports :not() in all browsers) or use the div[class] selector and manually loop through the results (in whatever language you're using) and remove items with style attributes. If it supports CSS3, the second selector will do everything you want in one go.

Comment: Your jQuery selector happens to be exactly how it's done with CSS. The `:not()` selector exists in CSS; the attribute not equals selector which only exists in jQuery is `[attr!=val]`, which may have confused you.

Comment: But that CSS selector is not supported in anything less than IE9. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: That doesn't mean it isn't possible with CSS.

Comment: BoltClock: thanks, you're absolutely right. I updated my answer to clarify that.

Answer (score -2):

Not possible with CSS if you want to support anything below IE9. You'd need JS.